# What is the reason for the presence of a developing region in a boundary layer?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, viscosity

[image]

Why does a fluid first flow as shown in the entrance region before flowing as shown in the developed region ?

In other words, why wouldn't it flow in developed region from the beginning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to no-slip boundary conditions, the fluid near the edges slows down. The entire fluid flow cannot adjust to this instantaneously due to viscosity. Therefore, it takes time for the fluid to reach its new equilibrium flow with the new boundary conditions imposed on it.

Comment: what is boundary condition or slip boundary condition.

Comment: @yuvrajsingh Comments on an answer is not the place to answer and ask new questions. If you have a new question, post it. However, you should do your research first. [Try starting here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132585/no-slip-boundary-condition-for-viscous-fluids)